# W3C GeoLocation and Safari

Tags: html, safari, geolocation, w3c-geolocation

Anyone know why Safari 5 does W3C Geolocation sometimes and then other times it just stalls out?

Example I have geolocation setup on my site. Today it worked fine in Safari then after 3 tests now it just does nothing. It prompts for permission but does not return successful or failed. BUT in FireFox it works fine.

Anyone else run into Safari 5 stalling out on W3C Geolocation? Like I said it's like a  50-50 on working.

Comment: Yes I find that Safari on Windows 7 fails silently for me in the case where there is not network connection, but also on Firefox when there is either not network connection or there is a network but not Internet. When there is Internet all browsers seem to call either a success or failure callback. Very inconsistent )-: